# Can Medicine Charms be applied to oneself?

Tags: exalted, exalted-3e

We are playing Exalted 3 and I'm the medic in the group.
Now we took some heavy (aggravated) damage and while it's obvious I can heal my comrads, I'm not sure if the medicine charms can be applied to myself.

The charms don't explicitly prevent it but they always talk about two people (the healer and recipient).

Are there any rules concerning "self healing" or is it up the group/game master to define how we deal with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the section on Treating Wounds with the Medicine Skill on page 236 it says:

> A character treating his own wounds raises the difficulty by 1.

Exalted is all about surpassing limits so I see no reason why this rule to the base skill wouldn't apply to all attempts at treating wounds with Medicine Charms.